# how to script copying documents

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

given a list of documents and their path in an access database what script do i need to copy all these documents from their path to a local folder without writing out each individual path into the script as the database often changes.

Comment: Are you writing this in VB6 or do you have access to new tech like .NET?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any "script" at all.  Just use a `FileCopy` statement, providing the source and destination paths.  It's right in the manual.

VB6 is compiled, not a scripting system like PHP or something.

Comment: I am using the file copy statement, that works fine, the issue is i have a list of over 100 documents with their path which changes frequently, so i cannot reference each path in the file copy statement. i need to reference to the table. at the moment i have

 Private Sub Command92_Click()

Dim sFile As String
Dim oFSO As Object

    sFile = Dir("C:\MyTest\volker1.xls")
    If sFile <> "" Then
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
        oFSO.CopyFolder "c:\temp", "c:\test"


        Set oFSO = Nothing
End If

End Sub .....but this only calls one folder at a time.